# WQL-Statement to check an application's event log

Tags: events, logging, vbscript, wql

I would like to analyze the event log of a special windows application (Windows 7 Enterprise, 64Bit).

I need a special event which is logged some seconds ago.

Here is my VBScript code, which produces a completely wrong result (wrong number of events):

strComputer = "." ' Dieser Computer

' Retrieving Specific Events from an Event Log

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Const CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME = True

Set dtmStartDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set dtmEndDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

dtmStartDate.SetVarDate dateadd("s", -10, now())    ' CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME 
dtmEndDate.SetVarDate now()                         ' CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME

dim var_wql

var_wql = "SELECT *  FROM  Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile =  '< ... >' AND SourceName = '< ... >' AND EventCode = '< ... >' AND  (TimeWritten >= '" & dtmStartDate & "') AND (TimeWritten < '" & dtmEndDate & "')"

Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery(var_wql)

...

The number of rows (anzahl = colLoggedEvents.count) must be 0 or 1, anything else is impossible.

What is wrong with the wql statement? I would like to check the last seconds in the past (from now).

Thanks.

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. If I change the objWMIService line to this, it works for me.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

Updated to grab ALL event logs created in the last 10 secs and write to log file.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strSystemDrive = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")
Const CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME = True  
Set dtmStartDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
Set dtmEndDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
dtmStartDate.SetVarDate dateadd("s", -10, now())    ' CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME 
dtmEndDate.SetVarDate now()                         ' CONVERT_TO_LOCAL_TIME
var_wql = "SELECT *  FROM  Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE (TimeWritten >= '" & dtmStartDate & "') AND (TimeWritten < '" & dtmEndDate & "')"
Set LogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strSystemDrive & "\Temp\EvtLog.txt", True)

Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery(var_wql)
For Each objEvent in colLoggedEvents
  LogFile.WriteLine "Computer Name    : " & objEvent.ComputerName
  LogFile.WriteLine "Logfile          : " & objEvent.Logfile
  LogFile.WriteLine "Type             : " & objEvent.Type
  LogFile.WriteLine "User             : " & objEvent.User
  LogFile.WriteLine "Category         : " & objEvent.Category
  LogFile.WriteLine "Category String  : " & objEvent.CategoryString

  If IsArray(objEvent.Data) Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(objEvent.Data)
      strData = strData & objEvent.Data(i) & ","
    Next
    LogFile.WriteLine "Data             : " & strData
  Else
    LogFile.WriteLine "Data             : " & objEvent.Data
  End If

  LogFile.WriteLine "Event Code       : " & objEvent.EventCode
  LogFile.WriteLine "Event Identifier : " & objEvent.EventIdentifier
  LogFile.WriteLine "Message          : " & objEvent.Message
  LogFile.WriteLine "Record Number    : " & objEvent.RecordNumber
  LogFile.WriteLine "Source Name      : " & objEvent.SourceName
  LogFile.WriteLine "Time Generated   : " & objEvent.TimeGenerated
  LogFile.WriteLine "Time Written     : " & objEvent.TimeWritten

  If IsArray(objEvent.InsertionStrings) Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(objEvent.InsertionStrings)
      strInsert = strInsert & objEvent.InsertionStrings(i) & ","
    Next
    LogFile.WriteLine "Insertion Strings: " & strInsert
  Else
    LogFile.WriteLine "Insertion Strings: " & objEvent.InsertionStrings
  End If

  LogFile.WriteLine "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"  
Next
```

Output sample (Not all fields used for every event) -

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Computer Name    : Randy-PC
Logfile          : Application
Type             : Information
User             : 
Category         : 0
Category String  : 
Data             : 
Event Code       : 9019
Event Identifier : 1073750843
Message          : The Desktop Window Manager was unable to start because the desktop composition setting is disabled
Record Number    : 37395
Source Name      : Desktop Window Manager
Time Generated   : 20160903031728.000000-000
Time Written     : 20160903031728.000000-000
Insertion Strings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```